# Submit spark job using SparkMagic + Livy with local jar file?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, livy

Does anyone know how to submit a spark job to Livy, via SparkMagic, but with **local** jar file as dependency?

I looked around (such as here: https://livy.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html), looks like Livy must require the jar file to be in hdfs already, and does not accept local jar file.

In our environment, our "client" machine is different from the Livy server.

Thanks!